# Cytoscape web 2 arbor layout

Tags: cytoscape-web

I've been trying to use the arbor layout. I've tried

```
layout: {
    name:"arbor"
}
```

and

```
layout: {
    name:"arbor",
    liveUpdate: true,
    ready: undefined,
    maxSimulationTime: 4000,
    fit: true,
    padding: [ 50, 50, 50, 50 ],
    ungrabifyWhileSimulating: true,
    repulsion: undefined,
    stiffness: undefined,
    friction: undefined,
    gravity: true,
    fps: undefined,
    precision: undefined,
    nodeMass: undefined,
    edgeLength: undefined,
    stepSize: 1,
    stableEnergy: function( energy ){
        var e = energy; 
        return (e.max <= 7) || (e.mean <= 5);
    }
}
```

In both cases the firebug console reports

```
arbor is not defined
http://localhost/WS/BioJS/biojs/src/main/resources/dependencies/cytoscape/jquery.cytoscapeweb.layout.arbor.js
Line 76
```

I'm I missing something? 
is there a working example of the arbor layout usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `arbor.js` in a `script` tag in your HTML.  The file `jquery.cytoscapeweb.layout.arbor.js` just interfaces arbor with Cytoscape Web.  Make sure you use the version of `arbor.js` bundled in the Cytoscape Web ZIP if you need IE support -- arbor doesn't provide this out of the box.

The reason why `arbor.js` isn't embedded in `jquery.cytoscapeweb.layout.arbor.js` is because `arbor.js` needs to be in its own `script` tag in order for web workers to work properly.  If you concatenate and minify `arbor.js` with your app's other scripts, arbor's path finding can break or arbor's webworkers could conflict with other webworkers in your app.

Comment: Thanks!. I just included the arbor.js file and my script is now working.